# Parameterized REST @Path

Tags: path, parameterized

I am at loss on how to get the parameterized @PATH to work.

Here is my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ND/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my resource class:

```
@Path("/ND")
public class TransactionResource 
{
@Context UriInfo uriInfo;

public TransactionResource() 
{   
}

@GET 
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String itWorks()
{
    return String.format("Get is OK. %s", DateUtil.now());
}

@GET @Path("/NJ")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String itWorksForState()
{
    return String.format("Get is OK for NJ. %s", DateUtil.now());
}

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String addTransaction(Transaction pTransaction) throws Exception
{
    //some code here        
    return "Successful Transmission";
}
```

When I do a GET or POST at the URL http://my_web_app:8080/ND then both methods work fine.
But for some reasons, the GET method at URL http://my_web_app:8080/ND/NJ always return the 404-NotFound.

What have I done wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 level of path :

1. The path of your web application **Context** in the server : Maybe **myapp**
2. The path of the Jax-Rs servlet in web.xml : Here /ND/, but I would suggest **/ws**
3. The path of the Resource : The first @Path above the class. You should probably have `@Path("transaction")`
4. Then an optional @Path above each method. Let's say that you dont add any @Path in any method.

Now you have 
    @Path("transaction")
    public class TransactionResource 
    {

```
    @GET 
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String itWorksForState()
    {
      return String.format("Get is OK for REST. %s", DateUtil.now());
    }
}
```

Go to Firefox and type 
 `http://my_web_app:8080/myapp/ws/transaction` : you should read the Date

If ever you add

```
    @Path("morepath")
    @GET 
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String itWorksForState()
    {
      return String.format("Get is OK for REST. %s", DateUtil.now());
    }
```

Then you must go to `http://my_web_app:8080/myapp/ws/transaction/morepath`